# How to add CSS class to <li> and <a> and id in a nav menu with code?

Tags: menus, css

I have registered nav menu. here is the code

```
<?php 
                    wp_nav_menu(
                            array (
                                    'theme_location' => 'top-menu',
                                    'menu_id' => 'navbarSupportedContent',
                                    'menu_class' => 'navbar-nav ml-auto',
                                    'container' => 'ul',
                                
                            )
                );  ?>
```

but `<li>` and `<a>` have classes that are not applied to the nav menu wordpress code. so how to add them?

```
<li id="f-one" class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#home">Home</a></li>
```

so any of f-one id or nav-item, nav-link added to the wordpress nav menu style. how to add them please?

Comment: Have you tried something like mentioned here, with CSS selector that picks out specifically the items you want to style https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-style-wordpress-navigation-menus/

Comment: thanks for reply. yes I had already checked  their topic before I posted my topic here. but they used the dashboard to add css while I want to add css styles with code. also my classes above already exists in the theme style.css but just not working. there are no spaces between links like home, blog ...and other  nav links in the nav menu. so I think the nav-link class not working

Comment: are you happy with adding styles to style.css? or you want to add the CSS itself using PHP too? I think as in their 'Method 2' it should be possible to do it with just CSS - it would be helpful to add the CSS you're trying to your question

Comment: thank you. I just have changed the theme after reseting. that was the problem and it is solved now and the style is as it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you. I just have changed the theme after reseting. that was the problem and it is solved now and the style is as it is.